# How can I slow down a program to make the request to the server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, dispatch

I need to know that the server is returned to display in a cell right inoformatsiya after editing or return the previous line, if an error occurs. Or I can get data asynchronously, and later to update the results of a cell?

The first press of the button allows the editing, the second store information on a server and object-question

```
var tempText:String!
        @IBAction func editButtonTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
            print("editButtonTapped")
            textIsEditable = !textIsEditable


            if textIsEditable == true {
                tempText = questionTextView.text
                questionTextView.isEditable=true
                questionTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            } else {
                questionTextView.isEditable=false
                questionTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

                question.questionText=questionTextView.text

                //Edit question on the server
                if question.editQuestion() == true {
                    print("return true")
                    if delegate != nil {
                        //delegate.editQuestionAction(question: question)
                        delegate.editQuestionAction(cell: self)

                    }
                } else {
                    questionTextView.text = tempText
                    question.questionText = tempText
                }
            }

        }
```

Method in Question class for server request:

```
func editQuestion() -> Bool {
        var edited=false

        //Prepare image for put
        let stringImage:String
        if questionImage == nil {
            stringImage=""
        } else {
            stringImage=imageName
        }

        let editDict:[String:String] = ["category" : category,
                       "text" : questionText,
                       "image": stringImage,
                       "id" : questionId]

        Connection.fetchData(feed: "quests", token: nil, parameters: editDict as [String : AnyObject]?, method: "PUT") { (result, responseDict) in
            if let success = responseDict?["success"] as? String {
                if success == "1" {
                    edited = true
                } else {
                    edited = false
                }
            }
        }
        return edited
    }
```

Method for request to the server:

```
static func fetchData(feed:String,token:String? = nil,parameters:[String:AnyObject]? = nil,method:String? = nil, onCompletion:@escaping (_ success:Bool,_ data:NSDictionary?)->Void){

        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

            //let url = NSURL(string: feed)
            if let unwrapped_url = NSURL(string: serverString+feed){

                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: unwrapped_url as URL)

                if let tk = token {
                    let authValue = "Token \(tk)"
                    request.setValue(authValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                }

                if let parm = parameters{
                    do {
                        if let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parm, options:[]) as NSData? {

                            //println(NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil))
                            request.httpBody = data as Data
                            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                            request.setValue("\(data.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
                        }
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }

                if let unwrapped_method = method {
                    request.httpMethod = unwrapped_method
                }

                let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
                sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15.0
                let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
                let taskGetCategories = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ (responseData, response, error) -> Void in

                    let statusCode = (response as! HTTPURLResponse?)?.statusCode
                    print("Status Code: \(statusCode), error: \(error)")
                    if error != nil || (statusCode != 200 && statusCode != 201 && statusCode != 202){
                        onCompletion(false, nil)

                    }
                    else {
                        do {
                            if let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData!, options: [.mutableContainers, .allowFragments]) as? NSDictionary{
                                onCompletion(true,dictionary)

                            } else{
                                onCompletion(false, nil)
                            }
                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }

                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                taskGetCategories.resume()
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE(import SwiftHTTP, need ios8):

```
func editQuestion(completion:@escaping (Bool)->()) {
        var edited=false

        //Prepare image for put
        let stringImage:String
        if questionImage == nil {
            stringImage=""
        } else {
            stringImage=imageName
        }

        let editDict:[String:String] = ["category" : category,
                       "text" : questionText,
                       "image": stringImage,
                       "id" : questionId]

        do {
            let opt = try HTTP.PUT(serverString+"quests", parameters: editDict)
            opt.start { response in
                //do things...
                if let err = response.error {
                    print("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(edited)
                    }
                    return //also notify app of failure as needed
                }
                let responseDict=convertStringToDictionary(text: response.text!)
                if let success = responseDict?["success"] as? String {
                    if success == "1" {
                        edited = true
                        completion(edited)
                    } else {
                        edited = false
                        completion(edited)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("got an error creating the request: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

now good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never make a remote request on the main thread**. That is a rule for any mobile platform, the app should always remain responsible to user actions, even when downloading or uploading data.

What you want to do is make the request asynchronously using whatever library you use (I recommend you have a look at Alamofire), and pass a **callback that should receive the response**. There you can use GCD (dispatch_async) to **update the UI from the main thread** (you can't change the UI from any other thread, on iOS at least).

Also note that Apple already deprecated methods to make synchronous requests on iOS (although they can still be done using semaphore or other forms of synchronization).

Comment: Looks fine to me, you don't really need the edited variable there, I'd just call completion(true) or completion(false) but that is a matter of preference. Also, often methods like this take two callbacks, one of which gets called when an error occurs. So if you for example want to show an alert after error inside editQuestion, pass in a callback that opens such alert and call it appropriately.

Comment: i think, i am understand you. Thanks.